# Flutter web: BlocProvider: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get$bloc' of undefined

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am getting this issue only in profile and release (web) build, but working all good in debug build.

So I am having this class, which gets access to the bloc in `didChangeDependencies()`

```
class _CategoryPageState extends State<CategoryPage> {
  BizBloc _bizBloc;
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _bizBloc = BizBlocProvider.of(context);
  }
}
```

BlocProvider is almost near the root of the application, defined in `main.dart` as follows:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return CityBlocProvider(
    child: CategoryBlocProvider(
        child: BizBlocProvider(
            child: MaterialApp( /** actual code goes here */ )
  )));
}
```

With this setup, its all working good in debug mode, but when in profile build, I am getting the following error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
js_primitives.dart:49 The following NullError was thrown building Builder:
js_primitives.dart:49 NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'get$bloc' on null
js_primitives.dart:49 
js_primitives.dart:49 Widget creation tracking is currently disabled. Enabling it enables improved error messages. It can
js_primitives.dart:49 be enabled by passing `--track-widget-creation` to `flutter run` or `flutter test`.
js_primitives.dart:49 
js_primitives.dart:49 When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
js_primitives.dart:49 TypeError: Cannot read property 'get$bloc' of undefined
js_primitives.dart:49     at Object.BizBlocProvider_of (https://bazon.in/app/main.dart.js:10277:126)
js_primitives.dart:49     at _CategoryPageState.didChangeDependencies$0 (https://bazon.in/app/main.dart.js:47315:25)
js_primitives.dart:49     at StatefulElement._firstBuild$0 (https://bazon.in/app/main.dart.js:85143:31)
js_primitives.dart:49     at StatefulElement.mount$2 (https://bazon.in/app/main.dart.js:85016:12)
js_primitives.dart:49     at SingleChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget$2 (https://bazon.in/app/main.dart.js:84733:16)
js_primitives.dart:49     at SingleChildRenderObjectElement.updateChild$3 (https://bazon.in/app/main.dart.js:84661:20)
js_primitives.dart:49     at SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount$2 (https://bazon.in/app/main.dart.js:85506:39)
js_primitives.dart:49     at StatelessElement.inflateWidget$2 (https://bazon.in/app/main.dart.js:84733:16)
js_primitives.dart:49     at StatelessElement.updateChild$3 (https://bazon.in/app/main.dart.js:84661:20)
js_primitives.dart:49     at StatelessElement.performRebuild$0 (https://bazon.in/app/main.dart.js:85039:41)
```

**Update 1:**

Now I have a parent Widget `HomePage`, whose `didChangeDependencies()` is as follows:

```
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    print('Home: Did Change Dependencies');
    print(context);
    print(CityBlocProvider.of(context));
    _cityBloc = CityBlocProvider.of(context);
    _categoryBloc = CategoryBlocProvider.of(context);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

Logs when I run above code locally is:

```
js_primitives.dart:32 Home: Did Change Dependencies
js_primitives.dart:32 HomePage(dirty, state: _HomePageState#eb8ac(lifecycle state: initialized))
js_primitives.dart:32 Instance of 'CityBloc'
```

But when I run the same code in `profile` build, the logs are:

```
js_primitives.dart:49 Home: Did Change Dependencies
js_primitives.dart:49 HomePage
js_primitives.dart:49 ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
js_primitives.dart:49 The following NullError was thrown building _BodyBuilder:
js_primitives.dart:49 NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'get$bloc' on null
```

The instance of HomePage looks different. The profile build is hosted @ https://bazon.in/app/#/

What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the errors, CityBlocProvider seems to be getting null. You may want to consider initializing `_cityBloc` inside initState() instead of didChangeDependencies().